# Github Public Key

Tags: github

what is the benefit of github''public key''. I created and added it to the setting in my account. However, when I try to authenticate it in my editor, I get the error below ? Please help. I created my Repo for the heck of learning github, so maybe I still did not get the point of setting a such a key in my account. [Inside of my terminal showing error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpGQE.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) acts like a lock and key. You give Github the public key (the lock) which only you can open with your secret private key. It's a simple way for Github to authenticate you.

Your computer has to be told which private keys to use. This involves adding it to your [ssh-agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-agent) which manages your private keys. See [Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) on Github for how to do this. And read the whole [Connecting to GitHub with SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) documentation.

Once this is all set up, you won't have to keep typing in your password.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I will definitely have a look at the links you have provided.